# Kotlin and autocollect appinsight-agent.jar

Tags: kotlin, azure-application-insights

I've successfully managed to log using the App-Insight library with Autocollect. While my logs with SLF4J can be sent to Azure Monitor, I'm encountering an issue where logs from my Kotlin classes aren't being captured, even though I'm using the same SLF4J library. How can I solve this? Has anyone else experienced a similar problem? I'm unsure of what to do. Perhaps I could use the Tracktrace method, but I'd prefer to find a solution using Autocollect.
i use  appinsight-agent version 3.5.1  appinsight-core kotlin/ java 17

Comment: i'm not sure i understand. you are using the app insight agent jar? that is all you need

Comment: please provide the Kotlin class file configuration with azure app insights.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm encountering an issue where logs from my Kotlin classes aren't being captured, even though I'm using the same SLF4J library.

Here, whenever we deal with app insights there will be some latency to get the trace logs if the configuration is in the correct format we will get trace logs after a while.

- Check with the below configuration.

Included dependencies for SLF4J, Logback, applicationinsights and the Azure Monitor appender for Logback
**build.gradle.kts :**

```java
dependencies {
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0-alpha1")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    implementation("com.microsoft.azure:azure-logback-appender:1.1.1")
    implementation("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-agent:3.4.19")
}
```

- Create a `logback.xml` file in the `src` directory.

**logback.xml :**

```xml
<configuration>

    <appender name="azure" class="com.microsoft.azure.logback.AzureAppender">
        <instrumentationKey>YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY</instrumentationKey>
        <contextField>properties</contextField>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="azure"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

- Use the API provided by the SDK to track telemetry data, such as events, traces, exceptions, and performance counters.

```java
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient

fun main() {
    val telemetryClient = TelemetryClient()
    
    // Track an event
    telemetryClient.trackEvent("MyEvent")
    
    // Track a trace
    telemetryClient.trackTrace("MyTrace")
    
    // Track an exception
    val exception = Exception("Something went wrong")
    telemetryClient.trackException(exception)
    
    // Flush telemetry data
    telemetryClient.flush()
}
```

**Traces :**

[image]

[image]

Comment: thx your right it took times to log my log in kotlin class. but i ts work. autocollect work with kotlin !!!